# Asynchronous WCF

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I am trying to create a WCF service that supports asynchronous calls. I followed all samples and tutorials I could find, and all of them have the customary pattern of one synchronous method, and the async Begin and End such as:

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = false)]
string GetData(int value);

[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
IAsyncResult BeginGetData(int value, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

string EndGetData(IAsyncResult result);
```

However, only the synchronous GetData gets called, no matter what I do on the client side. Fiddler tells me that the message is always the same:

```
 <s:Envelope
 xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetData
 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><value>0</value></GetData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

When I *remove* the synchronous GetData interface, the async method now is properly called.

Is this normal behavior? Is there anything else I should do to support sync and async versions of a method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common misconception. You assume that you need to make the server asynchronous in order for the client to be able to make async calls. This is not true. Server and client are 100% independent. They are separated by a binary wire protocol.

The message that you see in Fiddler is always the same because SOAP does not know anything about sync or async. At the SOAP level your decision does not manifest itself. For that reason the client cannot observe your server-side decision, either.

This means you can just make the server synchronous in still have a truely async client, or the other way around.

In any case, you should only implement *one* pattern on the server: Either sync or async. Never both. Get rid of one of your implementations. From a functional standpoint it doesn't matter which one stays.

I'm pulling up important information from the comments here:

> It is hard to fit an explanation about when to use server-side async
> into this comment box. In short, don't use it on the server by
> default. Use it if special circumstances make it attractive or
> necessary.
>
> On a meta-level let me point out that async IO has become
> a fad that should not be followed lightly. The community is in a very
> unfortunate state of misinformation about this right now.

Comment: That matches with what I see when running, it's just that all code samples I find include all of them. If the asynchrony is all in the client side then why bother with having async support on the server side?

Comment: The samples that you are looking at surely have just one implementation on the server, too. They might have both on the client, but on the server this never makes sense.; It is hard to fit an explanation about when to use server-side async into this comment box. In short, don't use it on the server by default. Use it if special circumstances make it attractive or necessary.; On a meta-level let me point out that async IO has become a fad that should not be followed lightly. The community is in a very unfortunate state of misinformation about this right now.

Comment: I have to agree with you there. I also sometimes see things done on a SOA way that could be a lot simpler by just having a db call.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't help much with comments such as "In general, if you have a choice between a synchronous and asynchronous call, choose the asynchronous call.
" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx